# C# - Why StreamReader ReadLine reading data before calling ReadLine?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader

I am using `StreamReader` over `NetworkStream` and I want just read one or more lines and another data is `byte array` (like file data) and I dont want to read that file data in `StreamReader`, for example I need to read text header line by line and when I see one empty line, header reads must end and next I must read bytes of file,
When I test this with `StreamReader` I get problems because `StreamReader` read bytes before I calling `ReadLine` (after first `ReadLine`) and after dispose `StreamReader` and using `NetworkStream` to read bytes I get block of bytes that is not start of file byte array after header, because `StreamReader` readed block of bytes in `ReadLine` and not called `ReadLine`.

What is wrong in StreamReader or my code settings?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream()))
{
    while (true)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        headerResponse += line + "\r\n";
        if (line == "")
            break;
    }
    using (var fileStreamReader = tcpClient.GetStream())
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        var readCount = fileStreamReader.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if you don't close the streamreader and continue to read also the byte buffer do you get your data correctly?

Comment: yes,I think StreamReader read block of data that I dont need it

Comment: What make you think that after closing the reader and then reopening it you are positioned where you left?

Comment: this is example,NetworkStream just read next data and if you read one block of data that is gon,for example if headers is 1024 bytes and you read 1044 bytes of data,20 byte gon from stream reader and next stream just read bytes from 1044 position

Comment: Then read the first part as bytes, convert to ASCII or UTF-8, determine where you should stop, continue reading as bytes. All from one stream.

Comment: My code edited in my real code I am using file stream reader in StreamReader block

Comment: @PatrickHofman is your mean I dont use StreamReader?

Comment: StreamReader *buffers* input, and can't be configured to not do so. If buffering of input is causing you issues (as it appears here), then you can't use a tool that uses buffering.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I think you right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created one CustomStreamReader and I read bytes one by one in ReadLine Method and fixed my problem:

```
public class CustomStreamReader : Stream
{
    NetworkStream CurrentStream { get; set; }

    public CustomStreamReader(NetworkStream currentStream)
    {
        CurrentStream = currentStream;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => CurrentStream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => CurrentStream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => CurrentStream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => CurrentStream.Length;

    public override long Position { get => CurrentStream.Position; set => CurrentStream.Position = value; }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        CurrentStream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return CurrentStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return CurrentStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        CurrentStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();
        do
        {
            int data = CurrentStream.ReadByte();
            if (data == -1)
                break;
            result.Add((byte)data);
            if (data == 13)
            {
                data = CurrentStream.ReadByte();
                if (data == -1)
                    break;
                result.Add((byte)data);
                if (data == 10)
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (true);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.ToArray());
    }
}
```